# Where does Hibernate Tools store its database connection info in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate-tools

I am using Hibernate Tools in Eclipse and having a problem. When we were initially trying to setup HT to be configured properly with our weird configuration, we made a custom DB connection (Right click your Hibernate configuration -> Edit Configuration - it's a dropdown box labelled Database connection:)

Now, we're not using that anymore, but it's showing up in the "Markers" section in Eclipse as having a couple of problems. We want to just delete it, but there's no option to do that that I can find in Eclipse, so I've been looking through the various XML files in .settings and .metadata.

I can't find it. At all. It's extremely well hidden. Even a search at the root of our workspace for text in the config doesn't find it.

Can someone tell me where they've hidden this thing so I can delete it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the eclipse installation directory?

```
<eclipse>/configuration
<eclipse>/configuration/.settings
```